# Generalization of parallelism - vector "parallel" to rows of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

#### Set up

I have the following quantities

- $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (assume $v\neq 0$)
- $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$
- $J\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $n > m$ and having full row-rank

I also know that the following properties hold
$$
\begin{align}
    a^\top v &= 0 \\
    Jv &= 0
\end{align}
$$

#### Question

> What can I say about $a$ and $J$? If $m=1$ then I can say $J^\top$ and $a$ are parallel, but when $m > 1$?

Intuitively my guess is that $a$ lies on the $\text{span}$ of the rows of $J$. Actually, $a$ is parallel to any row of $J$. Or maybe it's parallel to one of the rows?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio my bad, I meant row space

Comment: The condition is that $\ker(v^T)\supseteq \operatorname{Span}(a)+\operatorname{row}J$, which can be the case without necessarily $a$ being in $\operatorname{row}J$. Such a thing can in fact always be arranged if $\operatorname{rk}J<n-1$ and $Jv=0$.

Comment: You cannot say _anything_ about $a$ and $J$ as long as you don't rule out the possibility that $v=0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen In my problem I can definitely rule $v=0$ out, if it helps.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thank you. I just checked and in my problem I can assume WLOG that $J$ has full row rank

Comment: I think that the condition $\begin{bmatrix}a^\top\\ J\end{bmatrix}v=0$ is as basic as it gets. In the sense that you can say that it's the case if and only if $a$ and $J$ are in the same class of dickiness, where by *dickiness* I mean that their flumplurp is minimal, where a *minimal flumplurp* is something else, et cetera until you get that the algorithmic way to check all that is the very simple linear algebraic condition $\begin{bmatrix}a^\top\\ J\end{bmatrix}v=0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you. I suppose all I am looking for is figuring out what happens to the product $Ja$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Or rather. Under which conditions (additional too) can I assume $a = J^\top \lambda$ for some vector of coefficients $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Given $v\ne 0$ and $J\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ such that $Jv=0$, the following are equivalent: 1) $\operatorname{rk}J<n-1$; 2) there is some $a$ such that $a^\top v=0$ and $a\notin\operatorname{row}J$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Fair enough, I see your point. It can still be perpendicular to $v$ but not in the row space of $J$. In a way the fundamental theorem of linear algebra says that $\mathbb{R}^n$ decomposes as
$$
\mathbb{R}^n = C(J^\top) \otimes N(J)
$$
and so 
$$
a = a_{row} + a_{null}
$$
and what you are saying is that one can always find an $a$ where $a_{null}\neq 0$?